# Bootstrap: divide page contain in two(equal)

Tags: css, templates, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to use bootstrap to make webpage structure. I will be displaying two independent contain (some text on the left and some image on the right) so a would like to have a vertical division in two equal parts. Some this like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSUn2.png), some has a simple bootstrap template like this?

Comment: Please include the code directly in your question, as text, not as an image.  Anyone that wants to answer will want to reproduce what you already have, and making them retype it will make most people avoid answering the question.  Click the `edit` button below the question (directly above these comments) to make an update to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create two elements with relative size (or absolute, no matter) which is equal between each other (ahem left: 50% | right. 50%) to accommodate one to one side to the other this adding the property "float" in css; each aligned to their respective side.

**css**

```
.parent{
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
}
.left{
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
 display: inline-block
}
.right{
 width: 50%;
 float: right;
 display: inline-block
}
```

Comment: Some explanation of the solution is important.  This answer has been automatically flagged as low quality.  Code-only answers are frowned upon on SO, and will likely get you a lot of downvotes.  I'm not going to downvote, because I'm letting you know how it works, but others quite likely will.

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-6" id="left-column">
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-6" id="right-column">
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```